# how to unsubscribe in RxAndroid

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I have an Observable the on change of the value of an edittext, the value of in the edittext will be passed to the observer and set it to a textview as shown
in the code below.

what I am trying to do is, to unsubscribe the observable.
please help me unsubscribe the observable, my attempts are in the code belwo

```
//How to subscribe
//widgetObservable.unsubscribeOn();
//widgetObservable.unsafeSubscribe();
//widgetObservable.doOnUnsubscribe();
```

**code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private TextView mTextView = null;
private EditText mEditText = null;
private View mButton  = null;
private rx.Observable<String> widgetObservable = null;

Subscriber widgetSubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String  str) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNext: " + str);
        mTextView.setText(str);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            widgetObservable.subscribe(widgetSubscriber);

            //How to subscribe
            //widgetObservable.unsubscribeOn();
            //widgetObservable.unsafeSubscribe();
            //widgetObservable.doOnUnsubscribe();
        }
    });

    widgetObservable = rx.Observable.create(new rx.Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            subscriber.onNext(mEditText.getText().toString());
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just add this!

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    widgetObservable.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Subscription subscription;


subscription = widgetObservable.subscribe(widgetSubscriber);


if (subscription != null) {
  subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

The unsubscibe should be done in the Activity's onDestroy method

Comment: but i dont have unsubscribe() method, i have only the following:widgetObservable.unsubscribeOn();
//widgetObservable.unsafeSubscribe();
//widgetObservable.doOnUnsubscribe();

Comment: do NOT use the widgetObservable.unsubscribe() use the Subscription. unsubscribe(). You have to create Subscription object first ( See original answer)